# Create Field Value as Hyperlink using Reference from other column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm wanting to create a clickable link using JSON column formatting, for a product code (like CRM 31/22) by referring to a hypertext link in another column called CRM_URL.

I am trying this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href":"=@$CRM_URL"
  }
}
```

But it doesn't parse the content of the field called CRM_URL, it simply generates a hyperlink comprising the list URL + "CRM_URL".

What I'm trying to do is similar to [the example given in the MS documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#turn-field-values-into-hyperlinks-basic), but extracting the value from another column in the list.

Just can't work out the syntax.

Comment: What is the data type of CRM_URL column?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on field CRM Product Code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href":"[$CRM_URL]"
  }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Note**:

1. Make sure you are using [internal name](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/) of `CRM_URL` field. JSON formatting works with internal names and not displaye names.

Comment: I can now see and reference the internal name. 

However, my syntax is still incorrect, as the result is being constructed as the companyname.sharepoint.com/teams/SiteName/CRM_URL, not the URL that is in the CRM_URL field.

Comment: How the data stored in CRM_URL fields? Is it complete address with `https://`. Can you please add any screenshot of the data stored in CRM_URL field to see an example?

Comment: I don't know if I add a screenshot, but the field I am referencing is a complete address e.g "http://intranet/Corpcoms/MMI" ... etc.

The problem is that the syntax I'm trying is not creating a URL from the content of the field (which is valid) but just adding it on to the root URL of the list where it's located, which generates a valid (but incorrect) URL.

Comment: Try adding simple URL like `https://www.google.com/` in CRM_URL field and try testing this JSON and let me know if you still face the same issue

Comment: that is what I have. Maybe put it this way: in any SharePoint list, create two fields, A and B. In Column A, put the name of this Site: SharePoint Stack Exchange. 

In Column B, put the hyperlink of this thread: 
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/280042/create-field-value-as-hyperlink-using-reference-from-other-column/.

Now, format Column A such that when you click on the name, it launches the URL in Column B. That's what I'm trying to write the jSON script for.

Comment: This is what I am doing. check the attached image in my update answer where I have "Google" as a text and "https://www.google.com/" as a URL (Complete valid URL with `https:/` included in it).